# Grails - find all by presence of child obj in parent collection

Tags: grails, groovy

I have 2 domain classes: Project and User.

Project hasMany on User via a SortedSet called allowedUsers. User does not belong to Project.

I want to find all Projects that a particular user is allowed to see. So trying syntax like:

```
Project.findAll{ it.allowedUsers.contains( userA ) }
Project.findAll{ userA in it.allowedUsers }
```

These dont work. And the find notation doesn't appear to support something like a ThatContains operator.

How can I achieve my aim?

Comment: Also, createCriteria doesn't appear to support a 'contains' operator so don't think that will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Criteria should work, take a look at the "querying associations" section in http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria. Can you try the following:

```
def c = Project.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    allowedUsers{
        eq('id', userA.id)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `where` queries

```
def query = Project.where{
    allowedUsers{id == userA.id}
}

def results = query.list()
```

or HQL

```
def query = """
             select p from Project as p 
             inner join p.allowedUsers as user 
             where user.id = :user
            """

def results = Project.executeQuery(query, [user: userA.id])
```